# Pass in functionality to a method without any further changes to the class

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

I have the following logic which works fine where I am iterating an object and replacing string values if applicable.

But I am trying to make this more generic: I want the `replace` logic to come externally.

It is because I want the flexibility to be able to add on more manipulation functionality as needed.

I don't want to keep coming into this class and modify it each time. Instead looking to make it configurable.

Is there any approach I could take to achieve this?

For example I may want another logic where if the value is a string, I want to append "hello" to the string.

I *don't* want to do this:

```
private String addHello(String value) {
    return value + "hello";
}

// then in the parse method. 
if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
    field.set(obj, switchName((String) fieldValue));
    field.set(obj, addHello((String) fieldValue)); // new hello logic inserted
}
```

This would mean I am amending the class every time. Not exactly following [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principle.

It should be closed for modifications.

I am looking for advice on how I could turn this into being configurable so that I can stop touching the following implementation, but still be able to add on further logic to it.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.FieldUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class Helper {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void parse(Object obj) throws IllegalAccessException {
        if (obj == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
            Object fieldValue = FieldUtils.readField(obj, field.getName(), true);
            if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
                field.set(obj, switchName((String) fieldValue));
            }
            else {
                parse(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    }

    private String switchName(String value) {
        return value.replace("apple", "orange");
    }
}
```

Comment: Some context is missing, but possibly use of strategy pattern or maybe the decorator pattern.

Comment: @AndrewS Strategy is more of a selection of 1 functionality from 2 or more functionalities whereas I am looking to add on multiple functionalities. Guess decorator might fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to replace fields referencing a String, you could pass in a `Function<String,String>`.

```
public void parse(Object obj, 
   java.util.function.Function<String,String> replaceFn ) 
throws IllegalAccessException { ... }
```

If you want to be more general, you could pass in something that accepts an object and a field, and does something with it. Defining that as a specific interface makes it easier to find all implementations.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IFieldReplacer {
    public void accept(Object o, Field f) throws IllegalAccessException;
}

public class MyFieldReplacerA implements IFieldReplacer {

    @Override
    public void accept(Object o, Field f) 
    throws IllegalAccessException {

        // TODO Get the value, transmogrify it, and set it.

    }
}

public void parse(Object obj, IFieldReplacer fieldReplacer ) {
  ...
}
```

Both of these allow the caller to pass in a lambda expression.

Comment: This fits to what I was looking for. Only thing is this is for one method. I wanted to be  able to add on more methods as needed. In that case would the idea be to take in a 
List<IFieldReplacer> and loop over it and call accept for all the methods in it.

Comment: @kar - Another approach would be to build an IFieldReplacer that holds onto a list of subordinate IFieldReplacers. It's accept() method would iterate over them. With this approach, callers can choose to pass a single instance if desired. That single instance might be a composite. Or a composite of composites ...